# Can you add a search box on context menus?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have a pretty long context menu on Windows Explorer.

Is there a way to add a search box to the context menu that will allow me to quickly filter items?

[image]

The idea is to have something like this:

Default state → Searching

[image: default state] → [image: searching]

Comment: This is not a feature of Windows.  I know of no program that would add this type of functionality either.  What is and is not possible in a context menu is very specific.

Comment: submit it in the Feedback hub app and post the link here so that other can vote for it. Maybe MS ads it in 1703 if enough users voted for it.